# manipulating/filtering objects' props from an API with spread operator

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs, next.js, spread-syntax

Doing a React/Next course, in a momment we had to fetch an API returning a list of objects, with data to fill the page.

It is done on Next's getStaticProps, and passed to frontend as props, manipulating some of the data to best fit, and ignoring some too.
But to pass in a bunch os props that was not touched, required some extra typing:

```
data.map(episode=>{
    return {
      id: episode.id,
      title: episode.title,
      thumbnail: episode.thumbnail,
      members: episode.title,
      description: episode.description,
      url: episode.file.url,

      publishedAt: format( parseISO(episode.published_at), 'd MMM yy', {locale: ptBR } ),
      duration: Number(episode.file.duration),
      durationAsString: convertDurationToTimeString( Number(episode.file.duration) ),
    };
})
```

So i though of using JS's spread operation to make this code short, and less words hungry.
But i'm afraid of this aproach having any impact on performance, readability, code maintainability / test, all of those things.
Cause it doen't look a hard thing to come up with, so if the teacher didn'd do it, i may have some problem right?!

So please, take a look at this code, and say if is indeed a better solution, there's a problem in there:

```
const episodes = data.map(episode=>{
    const {
      file,
      published_at: publishedAt,
      ...rest

    } = episode;

    return {
      ...rest,
      url: file.url,
      duration: Number(file.duration),
      publishedAt: format( parseISO(publishedAt), 'd MMM yy', {locale: ptBR } ),
      durationAsString: convertDurationToTimeString( Number(file.duration) ),
    }
}
```

---

Here it is with line comments if it helps unsderstant what it means:

```
const episodes = data.map(episode=>{

    // filter out the data
    const {
      // attrs to remove from final
      file,

      // . to rename
      published_at: publishedAt,

      // to keep as is
      ...rest

    } = episode;

    // threat/manipulate and add data
    return {
      ...rest,
      url: file.url,
      duration: Number(file.duration),
      publishedAt: format( parseISO(publishedAt), 'd MMM yy', {locale: ptBR } ),
      durationAsString: convertDurationToTimeString( Number(file.duration) ),
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
const episodes = data.map(({ file, published_at: publishedAt, ...rest }) => ({
  ...rest,
  url: file.url,
  duration: Number(file.duration),
  publishedAt: format(parseISO(publishedAt), 'd MMM yy', { locale: ptBR }),
  durationAsString: convertDurationToTimeString(Number(file.duration)),
}));
```

This is the cleanest way I can suggest but your own code was readable enough and there is no performance cost in spreading objects as far as I know.

Comment: `You returned publishedAt at the end which results in having both publishedAt and published_at` why would it have both? There is no `published_at` left in `...rest`

Comment: ok, i get your point of detructuring direct on the argument, and the "straight" return of the arrow function. It takes less typing indeed.

I choose to separate it, to make it easier to unsderstand at a glance.

So the aproach in the end, is the same.

Comment: I did in fact, made a little console.Time tests.
Spread seems to have some tiny penalty:

no spread:

on yarn start:  4.384ms, 3.789ms, 5.31ms
on page reload:  1.147ms, 1.212ms, 1.175ms

with spread:

on yarn start: 4.869ms, 7.21ms, 5.951ms
on page reload:  2.325ms, 1.633ms, 1.771ms

Answer (score 0):

One more thing to note is that if you only want to return 9 properties that were listed in your first example, then your second example might not work that way if `episode` has more properties (at first you spread them into `...rest` and then destructure back with `...rest`). But if it is intentional then this way of doing things is totally fine.

Comment: I'm not sure i did understand. I was using these as example, but thinking in a more generic case: take an API responde; pass in some, not all; rename a fell; manipulate any data needed.  . No particular number of any those operations, or objects.

Comment: Let's say `episode` has `rating` property and you don't want to pass it to frontend. First example won't keep it and will return new object without it. Your second example will keep it and you will get object with `rating` property in the end.

Comment: Well, what was on my mind was to remove and rename explicitly, and keep untouched in a implied way. Because in this case the "don't touch" was majority. The first one is sure better for take just a few.